# Как правильно загрузить данные из базы данных в ViewPager

Tags: android, база-данных, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Мне надо, чтобы при открытии ViewPager из базы данных загружались данные только в тот фрагмент, на котором я сейчас нахожусь, а не во все фрагменты ViewPager'a. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: А как они сейчас у вас во все фрагменты загружаются?

Comment: @lsillarionov В классе FragmentManager есть метод getItem который возвращает новый фрагмент. В классе этого фрагмента есть метод onCreateView где загружаются данные из базы данных и кладутся в ListView фрагмента.

Answer (score 1):

Начинайте загрузку данных не в `onCreateView()` фрагмента, а в переопределенном методе **[setUserVisibleHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29)**:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && данныеЕщёНеЗагружены) {
        startLoadData();
    }
}
```

ViewPager выполняет `setUserVisibleHint(true)` каждый раз при показе фрагмента и `false` при его скрытии.